# multiple markers at this line error in comma and seprator

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]

Please refer this image find errors and give me the proper solutions for the same.

Comment: You could have debug it on your own. They just seem to be silly mistakes. It somewhat related to missing bracket / parenthesis

Comment: Please look up your Java syntax description and try it again.

Comment: Yeah but how i get resolve this?

Comment: @testuser is it inside static methods, try removing `static` keyword, `catch/throws IOException`

Comment: please share your code not a image so that easily sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `System.out.println()` for any class properties.

Declare any method and inside that use the `println()` to print anything.

Look at the following example:

```
public class Test {
    static String string;
    //the following println() will create the error: Multiple markers at this line 
    //- Syntax error on token(s) bla bla bla
    System.out.println("hello");

    public void printSomething() {
        //But this is ok
        System.out.println("hello"); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.printSomething(); // prints hello
    }
}
```

Comment: That file is use for Enter values from console so that i use System.out.println().  Actually i want to use all block of content use from another file which have declare all part of it.